# bash script taking input

Tags: bash

I have written a bash script. It is launched like this:

```
./myscript.sh $IP COMMAND-FILE
```

In COMMAND-FILE I give commands which I have to run on remote server. But now I have to use another script in COMMAND-FILE, like this:

```
yesSkip.sh $IP
```

My question is that how can I give input of IP which is showing in above line.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by 'giving input of IP'? Do you want to call this within the myscript.sh and pass the same arguments to the second script?

Answer (score 1):

You want to know how to use the `$IP` from the command line as a parameter to another part of your script? This is a little like *Bash 101* (Bash for Beginners), and it sounds like you could be recommended to spend some time going through a scripting tutorial.

However, to answer your question directly, each parameter is available as a numbered variable, `$1`, `$2`, and so on. So you can (re)use the first parameter like this:

```
yesSkip.sh "$1"
```

If you're really keen, at the top of your script assign the parameters to variables and use those (it helps with documentation of the code):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
IP="$1"
COMMANDFILE="$2"

...later...

yesSkip.sh "$IP"
```